# scanf to struct doesnt work

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I'm having this function and I need to get coordinates to a structure.
These are the structures:
//---------STRUCTURES----------

```
typedef struct coordinates  
{
    int x_l;
    int y_l;
    int x_r;
    int y_r;
} Coordinates;

typedef struct field 
{
    char Id;
    Coordinates location;
    int area;
    int price;
} Field;
```

and this is the function:

```
Field GetFieldFromUser(int cptr,Field *pf1)
{       
    //Field *pf
    int i=0;

    printf("\nPlease enter information for your new field:\n");
    printf("the Id of the field is 5 digit num between 00000-99999:\n");
    printf("The Id of the Field given Automatic by the system\n");


    pf1->Id= 0000+cptr;

    printf("\nThis is the ID for the new field: ");

    printf("id = %05d\n",pf1->Id);

    printf("\nPlease enter the coordinates of the top left of the field (press ' ' between the digits)\n");
    scanf("%d %d",pf1->location.x_l,pf1->location.y_l);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Please enter the coordinates of the lower right of the field (press ' ' between the digits)\n");
    scanf("%d %d",pf1->location.x_r,pf1->location.y_r);

    return *pf1;
}
```

now at the scanf of the location the compiler throw me out, and i dont know why

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf("%d %d",pf1->location.x_l,pf1->location.y_l);
```

should be

```
scanf("%d %d",&(pf1->location.x_l), &(pf1->location.y_l));
```

same logic for the next scanf. `scanf` expects addresses that it can write to. You were passing it values (uninitialized values probably). So it was trying to write to some unknown memory location.