# Why isn't scanf accepting elements into this C structure?

Tags: c, struct, structure, scanf

I'm new to C, and am studying structures. I created a simple structure and tried to enter input values through `scanf()` in the structure variables, but I'm only getting a partial/garbage output. Is there something I'm missing out here?

Here's my original code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    struct book
    {
        char name;
        float price;
        int pages;
    };

    struct book b1,b2,b3;
    int i;
    printf("\n Enter the names, prices and no. of pages of the 3 books: \n");
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b1.name,&b1.price, &b1.pages);
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b2.name,&b2.price, &b2.pages);
    scanf("%c %f %d", &b3.name,&b3.price, &b3.pages);   

    printf("\n You have entered: \n");
    printf("%c %.2f %d", b1.name,b1.price, b1.pages);
    printf("%c %.2f %d", b2.name,b2.price, b2.pages);
    printf("%c %.2f %d", b3.name,b3.price, b3.pages);
}
```

And this is the set of output-

```
Enter names, prices & no. of pages of 3 books
A 230.5 13
B 345.9 33

And this is what you entered
A 230.50 13

 0.00 3
B 345.89 33
```

As you can see:

1. As soon as I enter information about the second `structure variable(b2)`, the `printf()` stops working and doesn't accept info. about the third `structure variable(b3)`
2. When it abruptly stops accepting values through `scanf()`, I get some junk value in the second line- `0.00 3`

I thought maybe the structure definition should be outside `main()` always, so I even modified it to define the `struct book` outside `main()` and declare the variables `struct book b1,b2,b3;` inside main(), but it didn't have any effect.

What did I do wrong here?

**UPDATE**-

I know there exists a similar answer on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228239/scanf-to-struct-doesnt-work), but the problem here was that the `addressof(&)` operator wasn't included with `scanf()`

Comment: You are victim of trailing newline from previous input. You need a way to remove it (eat it) from input buffer.

Comment: so, should I use something like fflush(stdin)?

Comment: @DarkKnight `fflush(stdin)` is not defined in standard C. Even if it works on your machine, using it will make your program not portable.

Comment: Oh, I see. How do I get rid of the trailing newline then?

Comment: @DarkKnight `void eat_newline(){int c; while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ;}` or better alternative see YuHao answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you entered the first line of values, and press ENTER, the new line character is still in the input buffer and will be processed by `"%c"` in the next `scanf`.

To fix the problem, don't use `scanf`. Instead, use `fgets` to get each line and then use `sscanf` to get the values from each line.

Comment: Can you give a sample example? I've never used fgets with sscanf before, so.

Comment: @DarkKnight The usage of `sscanf` is similar to that of `scanf`, except it works on strings. You just need to learn how to get input lines using `fgets`, like `char line[100]; fgets(line, 100, stdin);`

Comment: Thank You, I'm aware of the format and method of using `fgets()` but wasn't sure of using `sscanf()` along with `fgets()`

Comment: @DarkKnight Use `line` as the first argument, with the rest the same as `scanf`:  `sscanf(line, "%c %f %d", &b1.name,&b1.price, &b1.pages);`

Answer (score 5):

Most book titles are longer than a single character, but the `%c` format limits the title to one character.  You structure also only stores a single character, so you'd need to change the definition to allow for a longer title.  More problematic, most book titles are longer than one word, but the `%s` format, which is the 'obvious' alternative to `%c`, only reads up to the first white space, which means it only reads the first word.

You should also check the return value from `scanf()` each time you use it.  If it is not 3, something went wrong.  The reason you have a problem is that the first line of input ends with a newline, which is not read by the `%d` format, so it is read by the `%c`, and then the numeric conversion fails on the letter.  You can fix that by using `" %c %.2f %d"` with a space before the `%c` to skip optional leading white space (which would skip the newline; it counts as white space).

There isn't a simple fix to this.  You need to know how to distinguish the end of the title from the price and the pages.  I'd probably use `fgets()` to read a whole line of input.  Then I'd scan backwards to find the number of pages and price; the residue of the line is presumably the book title.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void main()
{
        struct book
        {
                char name[99];
                float price;
                int pages;
        };

        struct book b1,b2,b3;
        int i,ch;
        printf("\n Enter the names \n");
        gets(b1.name);

        printf("\n enter the price\n");
        scanf("%f",&b1.price);
        printf("\n enter the pages\n");
        scanf("%d",&b1.pages);
        while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
        {
        }
        printf("\n Enter the names \n");

        gets(b2.name);
        printf("\n enter the price\n");
        scanf("%f",&b2.price);
        printf("\n enter the pages\n");
        scanf("%d",&b2.pages);
        while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
        {
        }
        printf("\n Enter the names \n");

        gets(b3.name);
        printf("\n enter the price\n");
        scanf("%f",&b3.price);
        printf("\n enter the pages\n");
        scanf("%d",&b3.pages);

        printf("\n You have entered: \n");
        printf("%s %.2f %d\n", b1.name,b1.price, b1.pages);
        printf("%s %.2f %d\n", b2.name,b2.price, b2.pages);
        printf("%s %.2f %d\n", b3.name,b3.price, b3.pages);
}
```